# How to overwrite data from a multi dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I got a multidimensional array where each array inside is a combination of all the user info (put in by the user)

I want the user to be able to modify his information, such as his name or phone number, so that the next time the user logs in, his new info is displayed.

The userList is saved on JSON, the idea would be for the changes to be saved and loaded from there.

Example:

if my array has

```
    userList= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userListLS')
     if(userList == null) {
userList =

      [
       ['Isaac', 'Garth', 'IsaacG11@email.com', 'Mazda']
       ['Matthew', 'Miller', 'mmiller21@mail.com', 'Volvo']
      ]
}
```

and lets say Isaac is logged in, and he wishes to change his name to Gabriel and change email to IsaacG21@email.com, so that the new array would be:

```
userList= [
       ['Gabriel', 'Garth', 'IsaacG21@email.com', 'Mazda']
       ['Matthew', 'Miller', 'mmiller21@mail.com', 'Volvo']
      ]
```

how could this be accomplished?

Only JS and HTML please.

Comment: @IssacG do you want only JS explanation or HTML tags too?

Comment: Can you change the structure at all? I would suggest using an array of objects instead of an array of arrays,

Comment: Hello. I edited the thread to mention that I'm using JSON, modified the code a bit to show the example of loading the JSON save. The JS explanation would be okay, I'm already using contenteditable for the HTMl form. The data is being updated, just not saved. Btw I'm using array of arrays (I think thats called a matrix?) because its the only method I know, I dont know what an array of objects is.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be to modify the data directly using index selectors:

> This approach mutates the initial array instead of returning a new reference, which can lead to unwanted side effects.

```js
function modifyData(data, userId, fieldId, newData) {
   if(data[userId] && data[userId][fieldId]) {
      data[userId][fieldId] = newData;
   }
   return data;
}

// example
var userList= [
  ['Isaac', 'Garth', 'IsaacG11@email.com', 'Mazda'],
  ['Matthew', 'Miller', 'mmiller21@mail.com', 'Volvo']
];
const FIELD_NAME_ID = 0;
const USER_ID = 0;

var modified = modifyData(userList, USER_ID, FIELD_NAME_ID, 'Morty')

console.log('initial', userList);
console.log('modified', modified);
```

An immutable approach would be:

```js
function modifyData(data, userId, fieldId, newData) {
   if(data && data[userId] && data[userId][fieldId]) {
      var _data = data.slice();
      var _user = data[userId].slice();
      _user[fieldId] = newData;
      _data[userId] = _user;
      return _data;
   }
   return data;
}

// example
var userList= [
  ['Isaac', 'Garth', 'IsaacG11@email.com', 'Mazda'],
  ['Matthew', 'Miller', 'mmiller21@mail.com', 'Volvo']
];
const FIELD_NAME_ID = 0;
const USER_ID = 0;



var modified = modifyData(userList, USER_ID, FIELD_NAME_ID, 'Morty');

console.log('initial', userList);
console.log('modified', modified);
```

But you should consider changing your structure to a dictionary of objects:

```
{
 user1: { name: 'Isaac', lastName: 'Garth' /* ... */ }
 // ...
}
```

or an array of objects (but then you have to find the right user in the array:

```
[
 { name: 'Isaac', lastName: 'Garth' /* ... */ }
 // ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good usecase for a Map:

```
const users = new Map(
  userList.map(
   ( [first,name,email,car]) => [first, { first,name,email,car }]
  )
);
```

So to change a certains users email:

```
users.get("Isaac").email = "test @ gmail.com";
```

A few more usecases:

```
//set a whole user:
users.set("Jack", {
 first:" Jack",
 name:"Daniels",
 email:"me@example.com",
 car:"VW"
});

//get an array of users again
userList = [...users.values()];
```